# $_SESSION disappear in ajax call due to size of $_SESSION

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I get some trouble with my php project.

In my $_SESSION, i record lot of multi array and data, he contain data from 10MB txt file .

after recording my data i use :

```
var_dump($_SESSION)
```

and this work well .

But if i call var_dump() in php file called by ajax i get this :

```
array(0) { }
```

my ajax file :

```
session_start();
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

why my $_SESSION is empty in my ajax.php ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: What you want is a database. Please do not try to store 10 MB in `$_SESSION`; that is just asking for a disaster.

Comment: i reporting all error and i dont get any one . . .
yes the best should be a database, but i realy want to use $_SESSION.
no semi-colon is missing, just a bad copy/paste

Comment: Can you explain WHY you want to store such a large array in Session?

Comment: i also work in localhost

Comment: for a google like project . all data is remenber in $_SESSION i dont realy want to use a database . . . do a grep will take lot of time, but if my data is recorded it will be realy faster

Comment: That does not explain why you want to store that much data in session. Understanding what the goal is would help us provide an solution. Also I do not see where you set your Session variable, so why would there be anything in it?

Comment: the data is set in other function, that work fine all data is stored in my $_SESSION but it's not appear only in my ajax . . .

i need to store this to be the faster .  if you want to find "cat" in lot of document, it can be realy slow, but if all word is remenber before request its realy fast . i know that the best should be to use a database but i dont want this

Comment: *"my ajax file "* - ajax file; ok. well, that isn't enough code here. If you're using ajax, then those 3 lines of code isn't ajax, it's PHP. This ajax https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Comment: yes sry this 3 line is the php file called by ajax .
the ajax call in php file work well

Answer (score 0):

Did you not put session_start() in your "recording" file? The max limit of a session is 128 MB by default, so you do not need to consider the size.

You write "due to size of $_SESSION", but you should not have assumed.